# Will it fix my problem if I repair an old MacBook through Apple?

Tags: macbook-pro, repair

I just went in to the Genius Bar with my 2015 MacBook Pro. They say I am having a hardware issue and they will have to repair it. They've told me it's a flat fee, so any problems they find will be fixed. Will my problem be fixed if I use this repair option? If it isn't fixed, will I get a refund?

Comment: What is the problem and what is their proposed solution?

Comment: It's kernel panicking and restarting frequently. They say it's likely the processor (an i7). They would like to send it in to repair it for ~500 USD

Comment: I would *strongly* recommend buying a new computer instead, based on the age of your computer and the repair price. I don't think it's worth putting that amount of money in. The MacBook Air or 14"/16" MacBook Pro machines are great.

Comment: That being said, yes it should fix it and if it doesn't you'd be reasonable to say you won't pay. You'd have to discuss with them to confirm exactly how it works.

Comment: @Ezekiel that was my immediate instinct but I don't necessarily have the money lying around for a new machine. I've thought about upgrading to a newer Intel Mac, but at this point Apple Silicon is the way to go it looks like.

Comment: You asked basically the same question [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/439892/is-it-better-to-repair-my-2015-macbook-pro-or-purchase-a-new-m1-macbook-for-deve).